# Cocos2d: help understanding setblendfunc to blend sprites

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

New to OpenGL and cocos2d and struggling to understand the setBlendFunc on sprites. Where can I get an explanation of the constants used.

I am trying to allow a user to rub away a sprite and see what is below it. This would only be for a certain sprite on the page.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try reading [documentation on OpenGL ES 1_0 glBlendFunc](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glBlendFunc.html)

I believe what you are looking for is `(ccBlendFunc){GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO}` as it will clear both source and destination or try `(ccBlendFunc){GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}` which will clear the source (the image with which you want to scratch the surface - circle or whatever make it to have alpha == 1 where you want it to clear and alpha == 0 (full transparency) outside the area) and will set the alpha of destination (background) to 0 as it will substract 1 from whatever was set there - most likely one as well.